# How to correctly batch a 2D FFT

Tags: c++, fft

Im using [clFFT](https://clmathlibraries.github.io/clFFT/) to run 10 data independent 2D FFTs (real to complex) with each one of size `N0 * N1`. I want to further batch each one of these independent FFTs with [clfftSetPlanBatchSize()](https://clmathlibraries.github.io/clFFT/clFFT_8h.html#a745f5b98386b73f9fc04395d30140d71) which lets you define in how many parallel FFTs the initial one should be seperated. Then I set the distance between the batches with [clfftSetPlanDistance()](https://clmathlibraries.github.io/clFFT/clFFT_8h.html#af185d2dd92f401f726f7fd84423a8791).
However, I don't receive the correct result at the end of the transformation, when setting the batch size > 1.

For example:

```
err = clfftSetPlanBatchSize(plan, 2);
err = clfftSetPlanDistance(plan, (N0 * N1)/2, floor((N0 * N1) / 2) + 1);
```

won´t give the correct results and increases the execution by 2. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong when batching 2D FFTs? Unfortunately I could not find any example for a batched 2D FFT with clFFT online.
Any help / suggestions are appreciated.